# QModelIndex.internalPointer() returning random objects and crashing

Tags: python, pyside2, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a TreeView with TreeModel with the drag & drop implemented as indicated in the documentation:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html

Everything was fine but after a certain amount of drag & drop movements the model started bringing random objects from `index.internalPointer()` in method `get_node(index)`.

```
def get_node(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        return index.internalPointer()

    return self.root
```

**The rest of the code at the bottom of the post.**

`.internalPointer()` should give me a `CriterionNode` object, but sometimes I get corrupt data, `CriterionNode` semi-empty objects or totally random objects. I even got objects (like `Line2D` objects) belonging to the matplotlib chart, whose logic is separated from the tree model.

**Video proof of the error**: https://mega.nz/file/3gwlQLyD#6JJnVFAZF5T13rCeGUUOQ7nx94YQXjquJc5YuBT8SVI

**Images of random object returning from internalPointer()**:

- random object 1

[image]

- random object 2

[image]

- semi-empty CriterionNode

[image]

I have made a minimal reproducible example in a **single script** `main.py`. I cannot make it shorter.

It is necessary to have PySide2 and matplotlib installed. I use `Python 3.8.2`. Although having 3.6 or superior is fine.

- `pip install Pyside2`
- `pip install matplotlib`

Run the script below and follow the steps in the next video to get random objects:
https://mega.nz/file/6sxnjKSb#w7uT0IzoGSgChTH5ZR-mzgbKS1CF5g6gkFTZ_PgMRDo

**main.py**:

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QMimeData
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

data = [
    {
        'data': [
            'Criterio 1',
            'descripcion\n1',
            'points',
            '0',
            '100',
            ['35', '38']
        ],
        'children': [
            {
                'data': [
                    'Criterio 2',
                    'descripcion\n2',
                    'metros',
                    '5',
                    '10',
                    ['2', '7']
                ],
                'children': [
                    {
                        'data': [
                            'Criterio 4',
                            'descripcion\n4',
                            'vatios',
                            '50',
                            '2500',
                            []
                        ],
                        'children': []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'data': [
                    'Criterio 3',
                    'descripcion\n3',
                    'julios',
                    '1',
                    '15468',
                    ['3', '5', '7']
                ],
                'children': []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'data': [
            'Criterio 5',
            'descripcion\n5',
            'voltios',
            '9',
            '5000',
            ['50']
        ],
        'children': [
            {
                'data': [
                    'Criterio 6',
                    'descripcion\n6',
                    'litros',
                    '0',
                    '999',
                    ['2', '8', '24', '68', '187']
                ],
                'children': []
            }
        ]
    }
]


class ChartCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, top=0.92)
        super().__init__(self.fig)

    def update_figure(self):
        # Clear axes
        self.axes.cla()  # same as self.axes.clear()
        self.draw()


class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super().__init__()
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def setModel(self, model):
        super().setModel(model)
        self.model().node_dropped.connect(self.update_selection, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.expandAll()

    def update_selection(self, row, column, parent_index):
        self.expandRecursively(parent_index)
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.model().index(row, column, parent_index))

    def currentChanged(self, current, previous):
        super().currentChanged(current, previous)
        if not current.isValid():
            return
        self.canvas.update_figure()


def add_children_recursive(parent, children_data):
    if children_data:
        for child_data in children_data:
            child = TreeNode(parent, child_data['data'])
            add_children_recursive(child, child_data['children'])
            parent.children.append(child)


class MyTreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    node_dropped = QtCore.Signal(int, int, QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.root = None  # The header data is in the root node data
        self._internal_objects = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.root) - 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.root)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            node: TreeNode = self.get_node(index)
            return node.data_at(0)

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent_index) -> bool:
        if row != -1:  # Inserting between nodes
            insert_pos = row
        else:  # Inserting in the node at the end
            insert_pos = self.get_node(parent_index).child_count()

        encoded_data = data.data('nodes')
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded_data, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        dropped_nodes = []
        while not stream.atEnd():
            droped_node = stream.readQVariant()
            dropped_nodes.append(droped_node)

        parent = self.get_node(parent_index)

        if row == -1 and dropped_nodes[0].parent == parent:
            return False

        correct_actual_index = insert_pos
        if dropped_nodes[0].parent == parent and insert_pos > dropped_nodes[0].row():
            correct_actual_index -= len(dropped_nodes)

        self.insertRows(insert_pos, len(dropped_nodes), parent_index)
        insert_pos = insert_pos
        for droped_node in dropped_nodes:
            index = self.index(insert_pos, 0, parent_index)
            self.setData(index, droped_node)
            insert_pos += 1

        self.node_dropped.emit(correct_actual_index, 0, parent_index)

        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled

    def get_node(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return index.internalPointer()

        return self.root

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.root.data_at(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row, column=0, parent_index=None):
        parent_index = parent_index or QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent_index):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        parent: TreeNode = self.get_node(parent_index)
        child: TreeNode = parent.children[row]
        if child:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child)

        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent_index=None) -> bool:
        parent_index = parent_index or QtCore.QModelIndex()

        self.beginInsertRows(parent_index, row, row + count - 1)
        node = self.get_node(parent_index)
        node.insert_children(row, count)
        self.endInsertRows()

        return True

    def load_data(self, criteria_data):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.root = TreeNode(data=['root'])
        add_children_recursive(self.root, criteria_data)
        self.endResetModel()

    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        encoded_data = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded_data, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)

        for index in indexes:
            if not index.isValid():
                continue

            node = self.get_node(index)
            stream.writeQVariant(node)

        mime_data.setData('nodes', encoded_data)
        return mime_data

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['nodes']

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        child = self.get_node(index)
        if not child or child == self.root:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        parent = child.parent

        if parent is None or parent == self.root:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent.row(), 0, parent)

    def removeRows(self, row, count, parent_index) -> bool:
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent_index, row, row + count - 1)
        node = self.get_node(parent_index)
        node.remove_children(row, count)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

    def rowCount(self, parent_index=None):
        parent_index = parent_index or QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if parent_index.column() > 0:
            return 0

        parent = self.get_node(parent_index)

        return parent.child_count() if parent else 0

    def setData(self, index, new_node, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole) -> bool:
        node = self.get_node(index)
        node.update_data(new_node)
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole])
        return True

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction


class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self._data = data or []
        self.children = []

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._data == other._data if isinstance(other, TreeNode) else False

    def __len__(self):
        if not self.children:
            return 1
        return sum(len(child) for child in self.children) + 1

    def child_count(self):
        return len(self.children)

    def data_at(self, column):
        try:
            return self._data[column]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def row(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.children.index(self)

        return 0  # Never used

    def column_count(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def insert_children(self, position, count):
        if position not in range(0, self.child_count() + 1):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            node = self.__class__(self)
            self.children.insert(position, node)

        return True

    def insert_columns(self, position, data_columns):
        if position not in range(0, self.child_count() + 1):
            return False

        for column in range(data_columns):
            self._data.insert(position, None)

        for child in self.children:
            child.insert_columns(position, data_columns)

    def remove_children(self, position, count):
        if position not in range(0, self.child_count() + 1 - count):
            return False

        i_to_delete = range(position, position + count)
        self.children = [child for i, child in enumerate(self.children) if i not in i_to_delete]

    def set_data(self, column, value) -> bool:
        try:
            self._data[column] = value
            return True
        except IndexError:
            return False

    def update_data(self, other: 'TreeNode'):
        other.parent = self.parent
        self.parent.children[self.row()] = other


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

model = MyTreeModel()
model.load_data(data)

canvas = ChartCanvas()
tree_view = MyTreeView(canvas)
tree_view.setModel(model)
tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)

layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(tree_view)
layout.addWidget(canvas)
layout.setStretch(0, 1)
layout.setStretch(1, 1)

w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I don't really know how `internalPointer` works with PyQt since a pointer is a thing from C++ domain. Have you considered using `internalId` instead of `internalPointer` which you could use as a key into some dict containing `CriterionNode` objects and then lookup in that dict in `get_node` method?

Comment: @eyllanesc He made an MRE.